# Splat (asterisk) operator on String

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

to write custom result of splat operator, one have to implement `to_a` method. Example for the String class:

```
class String
  def to_a
    self.split //
  end
end

irb> res = *'text'
=> ["t", "e", "x", "t"]
```

But without the above monkeypatch, the String class does know nothing about `to_a` method:

```
irb> String.respond_to? :to_a
=> false
```

So the question is, what method is called when applying splat operator on a standard "unpatched" String's object ?

```
irb> res = *'text'
=> ['text']
```

Comment: Don't overwrite `*` with Strings. It's already used as `'a' * 2 => 'aa'`. Changing its behavior causes madness in code maintenance people.

Answer (score 5):

First off: calling `String.respond_to?(:to_a)` will *not* tell you whether a string *instance* responds to `to_a`, it will tell you whether the `String` *class* responds to `to_a`. If you want to know whether a string responds to `to_a`, you have to ask the string:

```
'text'.respond_to?(:to_a) # => false
```

Or you can ask the `String` class whether it has a public instance method `to_a`:

```
String.public_instance_methods.include?(:to_a) # => false
```

Now, the *reason* why `String`s don't respond to `to_a` is because it's not clear what you want: do you want an array of characters? Of glyphs? Of lines? Of codepoints? Of bytes?

```
a = *'text'.chars      # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = *'text'.codepoints # => [116, 101, 120, 116]
a = *'text'.bytes      # => [116, 101, 120, 116]
a = *'text'.lines      # => ['text']
```

As to why the splat operator behaves the way you are seeing, that seems to be a corner case in the language specification. I am not even 100% sure that this is intended behavior. The specification for multiple assignments runs almost 4 pages, see section 11.4.2.4 of the Ruby Language Specification for details.

Comment: It's intended in the sense that it's (unofficially?) tested for ;)

Comment: Thx for the correction concerning the class/instance method calls. Just've wrote too fast.

Answer (score 3):

[Splat, by definition, returns the value in an array if the object doesn't respond to `to_a`:](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/splat_spec.rb#L51)

```
it "assigns the splatted object contained into an array when the splatted object doesn't respond to to_a" do
  a = *1; a.should == [1]
end
```

Caveat: somewhat unofficial, but relatively usable.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the issue. I'm still discovering Ruby has too many *special cases* to my taste.

Comment: @DavidUnric That's generally the case in relatively organic languages like Ruby. I'm not sure if I consider this a special case or just a specific default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is sufficiently sublime for your needs, but you can do:

```
1.9.3-p0 :008 > res = *'text'.chars
 => ["t", "e", "x", "t"]
```